# Does somedody know how to reverse digits in right order with recursion in c

Tags: c, recursion, binary

I have a task to convert decemiacal number to 8-binary. from 1 to 100, i don't  know how to reverse dights in right order/ i use recursive,  i mean
output is: 3 4 1, what it should be 1 3 4/ How to reverse a few numbers)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int bit8(int n) {
    int x = n;
    if (n == 100) {
        return 1;
    }
    int mass[100];
    int b;
    int i = 0;
    printf("%d: ", n);
    while (x >= 8) {
        b = x % 8;
        x = x / 8;
    }
    if (x < 8) {
        printf("%d ", x);
        i++;
    }
    bit8(n + 1);
}

int main() {
    int n = 1;
    bit8(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> to convert <strike>decemiacal</strike> number to 8-binary

Suggest starting over.

Typical recursion first tests before maybe recursing.

To print an n-bit integer number:

```
void print_n_bit(unsigned value, unsigned bit_count) {
  if (bit_count > 0) {
    if (bit_count > 1) {
      // Print the other, more significant, bits first.
      print_n_bit(value >> 1, bit_count-1);  // Recursive call
    }
    // Now print the least significant bit
    putchar((value & 1) + '0');
  }
}
```

Usage example:

```
int main(void) {
  unsigned n = 1;
  unsigned bits_to_print = 8;
  print_n_bit(n, bits_to_print);
}
```